# Proper procedure to restart/reload Apache/PHP-FPM combo

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, apache2.4, php-7.3

I have tried to find some documentation about this (failed) but how to properly restart/reload/graceful a Apache/PHP-FPM combo (using sockets)?

I have had problems when editing one of the Apache .conf files, I cannot only do a "apachectl graceful", sometimes I have to fully restart both as the sites are not responsive, sometimes twice.

I also had problems when I changed a setting for PHP-FPM, just reloading PHP-FPM will (sometimes) not do - I have to restart them both.

Is there any documentation around that describes the proper process, e.g.:
 - what to do when editing apache conf files only
 - what to do when editing php-fpm config files only?
and then restarting either one or both.

Also is the order important?